# I'm trying to identify and find The manufacturer of a shower valve that is stamped gobo asse 1016

Tags: water, shower, leak, plumbing-fixture

I have been looking for hours online I have an old shower valve that's leaking everywhere and I just need to find a part that will be the same as this one but I cannot even find who makes this part. It is stamped gobo asse 1016 I have a single handle please help

Comment: maybe you are misreading the label... please add a picture

Comment: without a picture we can not help you...https://duckduckgo.com/?q=gobo+asse+1016+valve&t=osx&iax=images&ia=images&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ebayimg.com%2Fimages%2Fg%2F03EAAOSwbS1cv2fw%2Fs-l400.jpg

Comment: Pictures would be good, but the usual advice is to turn the house water off; remove the offending part; then take it to a good plumbing store for replacement/repair parts.